# Fastest way to remove hundreds elements from JsonArray

Tags: .net-core

What would be the fastest way to remove hundreds elements from `System.Text.Json.Nodes.JsonArray` that meet some criteria?

I have `JsonArray` with literally hundreds of elements and most of them is the garbage so I need to leave only the ones that meet specific criteria.

Is there any way to do something like this?

```
jsonArray.RemoveAll(e => /* any criteria */)
```

I'm looking fastest solution and not really tied up to `JsonArray` and can use anything else that fits better to it.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATED**

Example of JSON file

```
        [{
            "timestamp":"2023-03-13T15:21:24.057Z",
            "type":"Gateway",
            "mac":"AC233FC0F654",
            "gatewayFree":23,
            "gatewayLoad":0.39000000000000001
        },
        {
            "timestamp":"2023-03-13T15:21:24.057Z",
            "type":"Unknown",
            "mac":"157007098D2E",
            "bleNo":0,
            "bleName":"",
            "rssi":-67,
            "rawData":"02011A07FF4C0015020034"
        },
        {
            "timestamp":"2023-03-13T15:21:24.058Z",
            "type":"Unknown",
            "mac":"147D21B57EB9",
            "bleNo":0,
            "bleName":"",
            "rssi":-78,
            "rawData":"0201060309536B16FF53500004F6400201020304FBE705060708040102FF"
        }]
```

Comment: Do you have example of your JSON object?

Comment: @khaledDehia, added example of JSON. This is the shorten version... in reality the array will have hundreds of elements inside

Answer (score 0):

To remove elements from a JSON array, you can use the splice() method. This method modifies the original array by removing or replacing existing elements and returns the removed elements as a new array

Comment: there is not splice method in `JsonArray`

Answer (score 0):

you can use LINQ to quickly filter the elements of a JsonArray that meet specific criteria

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. As it’s written, your answer doesn’t give enough information that the average reader is going to understand how to use it to solve a similar problem. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details and to clarify your recommendation for the benefit of the community?** Regards.